# Ionic 2/3: Runtime Error: Property undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

First of all I'm using Ionic 3.x on macOS.

I'm trying to push some data, into an array.

Within the export class I defined it.

```
export class HomePage {
   tables: any[]
   //...
   addTable(){

    let prompt = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Add Table',
      subTitle: 'Enter the table number',
      inputs: [{
        name: 'tableNumber',
        placeholder: 'Number',
        type: 'number'
      }],
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel'
        },
        {
          text: 'Add',
          handler: data => {
            let table = {
              number: data.tableNumber,
              name: 'occupied'
            }
            alert('Success');
            this.tables.push(table);
          }
        }
      ]
    });
}
```

When I test the app in Ionic lab and add a table it gives me the error: Runtime Error
_this.tables is undefined.

The 'Success' alert gets displayed, so the app crashes at this.tables.push(table); , but I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ionic uses **Type**script, it's very important that you understand the difference between *declaring the type of a property* and *assigning a value to a property*.

Doing `tables: any[]` you're just saying that the `tables` property is a property of the type `any[]` (so an array of anything). **But you are not initializing that property, it's just undefined by now**

Since it's undefined, when you try to call the `push` method using it, you get that error.

To solve the issue, **initialize** the `tables` property to an empty array so you can then call the `push` method on it:

```
public tables: any[] = [];
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You are right, I'm still struggling with typescript. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped :)

Comment: May I ask you a quick follow up question?
I'm now trying to display the pushed value in my HTML file.
So I wrote:
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let table of tables">
      #{{ tables.number }} Status: {{ tables.name }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

but unfortunately the values don't get displayed. The only thing printed after the data has been pushed is "# Status:".
Any idea how to fix this? :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 tables: any[]
```

change this to

```
tables: any=[];
```